# How do you change the orientation to landscape only in IOS 6?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Please give me a detailed response. I am very new at programming.

In my MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard, I created have a View Controller with some UIImageViews on it. In my attributes inspector of my View Controller, I changed the Orientation to Landscape. I also implemented the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method and the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` method like so:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

What is happening, is that my application launches in landscape mode, however, it seems like all my UIImageViews for some reason went through some sort of unnecessary automatic struts and springs process so that the UIImageViews aren't placed the way they appear on my storyboard. My goal is to have my application be in landscape only mode while my UIImageViews stay in the same place they appear in the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{ 
NSLog(@"self.viewControllers>>%@",self.viewControllers); 
NSLog(@"self.viewControllers lastObject>>%@",[self.viewControllers lastObject]); 

return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate]; 
} 

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{ 
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations]; 
} 

@end 

//After adding the custom class in ur project: 

#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 ) 
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 ) 
//Add dez methods for orientations: 

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark ORIENTATION 

#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
// Return YES for supported orientations. 
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); 
} 
#endif 


#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{ 
return YES; 
} 
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{ 
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight; 
} 

#endif
```

Source: the [last answer](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Xcode-451-ios-6-orientation-121874.S.172518065) from [Mr Kumar-Rami](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?viewMemberFeed=&gid=121874&memberID=184297377)

Comment: I replaced the answer with one which appears handle the versioning issue.

Comment: it is not necessary to check the systemVersion… with if… etc. Just simple…. write all methods… the iOS will know to handle it...